# Is it correct to say "I cannot see things that I don't know exist?"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say

> 1.) I cannot see things that I don't know exist

or is it better to say

> 2.) I cannot see things that I don't know existed

If 1.) is correct, then the grammatical structure is know+exist, which is verb+verb.

I am not sure whether a verb+verb is correct.

Comment: (2) also has the two adjacent verbs, but it's a much more confusing sentence. Seeing and Knowing are happening now, but Existing happened in the past, and I can's see how past Existing can be relevant to present Seeing and Knowing.

Answer (score 4):

Both are grammatical, but the first (with "exist") is more likely because of the meaning. The structure is normal in speech, but may be confusing in writing.

The grammatical structure isn't "know + exist" - these two words come from different parts of the structure, and are consecutive by accident.

The structure is:

> I don't know (that) things exist.

('that' in brackets because it is optional).

Make it into a relative clause

> things [(that) I don't know (that) *t* exist].

We've taken "things" out of the clause, and left *t* (grammarians call this a 'trace') that represents what has been removed. Since the trace doesn't actually have any realisation as words, the second 'that' is not grammatical and must be omitted, leaving 'know' next to 'exist':

> things I don't know exist.

Then we embed this complex noun phrase in a sentence:

> I cannot see things that I don't know exist.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation on the grammatical structure is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could give more context but, with what is offered I would make the following comments:

> I cannot see things that I don't know existed?

Don't is current tense and existed is past tense, I would align those so that either both are past *"I cannot see things that I didn't know existed."* or both current *"I cannot see things that I don't know exist."*.

I would also ask why there is a question mark at the end of the phrase when it is more of a statement. Also, you can usually remove "that" from most phrases and be good to go. Context would help.

Finally, depending on context, I would suggest that (assuming that this is a response to the question "Why didn't you see that by closing the spigot the frog in the drain would be parched? (is that too much of a stretch...not feeling creative this morning...sigh) I would answer, I cannot account for things whose existence is unknown to me.

Comment: You were asking:

Comment: You were asking: why there's a question mark at the end of the phrase because I was asking "Is it correct to say ...?" So that was a question. Perhaps I should have moved the question mark out of the quotation marks?

Comment: No worries, just making sure it wasn't part of the phrase you were making inquiries about.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot see things that I don't know exist* is probably what you're going for, and it is correct. You cannot see things, in the present tense, if you do not know that they exist, also in the present tense.

You would only use "existed" if you're referring to their existence at a time in the past. The timeline here is definitely more confusing, so I'm going to assume that your intentions were with the first example.

I know it feels weird to have that verb+verb setup (know+exist), but it is grammatically correct. If the setup still bothers you, I would suggest rewording the statement.

Comment: @DHsu You're very welcome!